# Trying to parse a JSON file but it returns me _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm trying to parse a remote json but I always get this error `_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')`, I tried to simplify as much as possible the examples because my model is a bit complex and the JSON has more than 5000 words.

Here's my function:

```
Future<void> updateCrypto(String symbol) async {

    Uri url = Uri.https(); // url where I get the json

    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);

      final parsedJson = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final Cryptocurrency updatedCrypto = Cryptocurrency.fromJson(parsedJson);

    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }
```

My model:

```
class Cryptocurrency with ChangeNotifier {
  Cryptocurrency({
    required this.id,
    required this.symbol,
    required this.name,
    ...
  });

  late final String id;
  late final String symbol;
  late final String name;
  ...

  factory Cryptocurrency.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Cryptocurrency(
        id: json['id'],
        symbol: json['symbol'],
        name: json['name'],
        ...
  }
}
```

Json example (cut because it's a 5000 words json file):

```
{"id":"bitcoin","symbol":"btc","name":"Bitcoin",   }
```

Comment: What is the first portion response

Comment: @YeasinSheikh it starts like in the example,so `{"id":"bitcoin","symbol":"btc","name":"Bitcoin","asset_platform_id":null,"platforms":{"":""},"block_time_in_minutes":10,"hashing_algorithm":"SHA-256","categories":["Cryptocurrency"], ... ` , it should be like a single item, not a list or array

Comment: Isn't it actually `"{"id":"bitcoin","symbol":"btc","name":"Bitcoin",   }"` maybe? The error implies that the result of json.decode is a string instead of a map, which as far as I know only happens when the response has `"` around it

Comment: what type did you consider for platforms ?string or map?

Comment: @Ivo No, unfortunately, there aren't " to wrap it

Comment: @eamirho3ein map, tried also removing it from my model but I still get the same error

Comment: I think it is related to one of you variable in you model. please add the hole code of your model.

Comment: I suspect of using `fromJson`

Comment: @eamirho3ein Stackoverflow says I can't post it unfortunately, `Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 30826.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh so the best way to debug in this case is to delete piece of code from model and see if it works?

Comment: yap, also I think I will prefer modification on model class itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to modify the entity and use case like

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class Cryptocurrency with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String symbol;
  final String name;
  Cryptocurrency({
    required this.id,
    required this.symbol,
    required this.name,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final result = <String, dynamic>{};

    result.addAll({'id': id});
    result.addAll({'symbol': symbol});
    result.addAll({'name': name});

    return result;
  }

  factory Cryptocurrency.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Cryptocurrency(
      id: map['id'] ?? '',
      symbol: map['symbol'] ?? '',
      name: map['name'] ?? '',
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Cryptocurrency.fromJson(String source) =>
      Cryptocurrency.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

And use case

```dart
     final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
     final parsedJson = json.decode(response.body);

     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final Cryptocurrency updatedCrypto = Cryptocurrency.fromJson(data);
```